# NullPointerException on getText() call

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm learning Android and I have a very simple interface. I'm only trying to print to console the content of an `EditText`, but getting an error right from the beginning,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    EditText BillET;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BillET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bill_edit_text);
        System.out.println(BillET.getText().toString());
    }
...
}
```

My layout file is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bill_edit_text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm getting an null pointer exception. Any idea about why this error is occuring?

```
02-19 21:20:25.280    9835-9835/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 9835
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post `activtiy_main.xml`? and get text on button click event

Comment: ok, I've added the layout file

Comment: As you're learning, please also read the Java naming conventions.  `BillET` should we `billET`.  The class name should start with uppercase, the instance variable starts with lowercase.

Comment: Please add `android:text="Hello World"` to the XML, does it still happen?

Comment: anyway, you should know that this is not going to log anything, as there is nothing in the edittext at this point.

Comment: yes, I was just checking, no adding the Hello World still cause the problem

Comment: Move this `System.out.println(BillET.getText().toString());` to `onStart()`.  Same problem?  If same problem, then comment it out.  Does your app display "Hello World" correctly?

Comment: Preface the line in question with `System.out.println("BillET is " + BillET);` and I believe your log will show that you have not successfully obtained the EditText.

Comment: As you're learning, now would also be a really good time to start using the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on `findViewById`.  Step over it.  Is `BillET` null?

Comment: yes, it is, but i don't understand why

Comment: Yes it is what? The app works if you comment out the `System.out` call? If so, did you try Chris Stratton's recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(BillET.getText().toString());
```

Two possibilities either your `BillET` will be null or `BillET.getText()` returns null

Comment: Surely only an Android framework bug, which would be widely known on such a common method, could cause `getText()` to return null?  It must be `BillET`.  Without XML, hard to see why.

Comment: Ok, I've added the xml file

Comment: Not a bug you have not set any text in xml for EditText so it returns null :)

Comment: I never knew that.  I assumed it returns an empty `CharacterSequence`.

Comment: its not solving the error, I've initialise BillET and now it even contains Hello World

Comment: Where you are seeing this hello world, you sure you are setting the right lay_out for the activity

Comment: @RajeshCP - actually no.  Examining the source code, EditText inherits from TextView the constructor of which initializes the internal field to an empty CharSequence, so it will be empty rather than null.   And the implementation of setText() replaces a null argument with an empty non-null one.